# Pointers and addresses in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-address

I am messing around a little with pointers. Please take a look at the following results (addresses).

1st code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int a = 5;
    void* pointer = &a;
    std::cout << a << std::endl << &a << std::endl;
    std::cout << pointer << std::endl ;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Result:

[image: result1]

2nd code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int a = 5;
    void* pointer = &a;
    std::cout << a << std::endl << &a << std::endl;
    std::cout << &pointer << std::endl ;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Result:

[image: result2]

Why does the address of the variable `a` change between the two codes?

Comment: please clarify: are you asking for the difference between `0x7bfe14` and `0x7bfe1c` ? Or something else?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number yes , why did the adress of a change ?

Comment: The address of the variable `a` changes because different isn't the same. The variable `a` holds an `int` value, and that value is set to 5. That's the same for both pieces of code. Don't get hung up on **where** the variable is stored; that information is sometimes useful **inside** a program, but there is no requirement that `a` be in the same place in two different programs, or even in the same program when it's run more than once.

Comment: why `a` doesnt have the same adress? Why should it?

Comment: The address contained by a pointer is not the same as the address of that pointer. `pointer` contains a value (it stores an address) and that value has to itself also be stored somewhere. `&pointer` is the address of where `pointer` stores that value.

Comment: `&pointer` is the address of the variable containing the address of `a`. Pointers are variables too, and thus have addresses of their own.

Comment: @PeteBecker i thought that there is an order the computer follows to store variables , i did not add or delete any variables between the two codes so why would the computer change the order in which it stores or affects addresses

Comment: Forget the 2nd code. It's a distraction. Just run the 1st code more than once, and you'll see that `&a` changes between invocations. The operating system allocates memory/stack space to the process using available memory, which is constantly changing.

Comment: @CherryDT i don't think accessing the pointer's address changes anything since the `pointer` did have an address in the first code too, otherwise i would'nt be capable of accessing the address of `a` which is stored in the pointer which exists somewhere in the memory so it can store something inside it

Comment: Your question would have been clearer if you had chosed any value except `&a` for `pointer`.

Comment: @KenZa no, that variable doesn't need to exist in the 1st code, it's optimized away. All you do with it is storing one fixed value and reading it back afterwards, so there is no need to even have this variable, and the compiler won't use it. The compiler can handle it as if you had written `&a` instead of `pointer` in the 2nd output line, saving some space and execution time.

Comment: @KenZa Look at it this way: someone asks you on the phone to write down the word "apple" and then read it back. You'll probably just remember it in your head and reply "apple" without really writing it, because it doesn't matter and the person can't know, and you'll save some time and a piece of paper this way. Next time they ask you to send them a picture of the paper instead, with the word "apple" written on it. Now you _do_ have to actually write it down. So, before, you didn't need a paper, now you do.

Comment: @CherryDT i seem to have a fundamental misconception about pointers, to me a pointer is a variable and it contains a value ( which is an address ) so it must have and address so we could access the value stored inside , just like `a` is an integer and it contains a value which is 5 so it must have an address in order to access the value stored in it

Comment: @CherryDT oooh i think i  get it now , but if i add `cout << b` then b should have an address in this case right ?

Comment: @KenZa to get a better understanding, you can use Compiler Explorer: https://godbolt.org/ - see what code gets generated. You need to learn assembly for that though, but I'd recommend that anyway as a way to better understand how things work under the hood, it can come in handy later - for debugging, optimization, understanding security vulnerabilities, etc

Comment: @CherryDT oh so when you said " none of these variables have to really exist " `c` is included in this statement

Comment: @CherryDT this is making me feel so weird , for instance if i needed to perform some others operations on the variable `c` how does the compiler find it if it is not stored somewhere

Comment: @CherryDT and also when we debug `for( int i = 0 ; i < 5 ;  ++i]`  for example , i think the debugger does show us the address of `i` and it's new value after each itereation so did the compiler decide that `i` needs to have and address in this case ?

Comment: @CherryDT so i presume in the 1st code the pointer was stored in some register in the CPU ,whereas in the 2nd code it had to be stored in the RAM in order to be displayed therefore changing the address of  `a` to make room for it , is that it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239125/discussion-between-cherrydt-and-ken-za). (I cleaned up my other comments here.)

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you never take the address of `pointer`, so `pointer` can be stored in a register, or even not at all. (Modern compilers are very clever, and modern machines have many registers.)

For instance, gcc 11 keeps the value in a register without optimization, and with `-O2` it just inserts the address of `a` directly. (Assembly [here](https://godbolt.org/z/PY6j8YdTj), for the curious.)

In the second case, you *do* take the address of `pointer`, so it must be stored somewhere in memory.
This means that `a` might be stored in a different place in order to make room for it.

Also, some platforms randomize storage locations in order to make programs less hackable, so it's usually not a good idea to assume that things will have the same address in different "runs".

Comment: in the first case it is possible for the pointer not to have an address ? but i thought that `pointer` is a variable so it is stored somewhere since it is a variable and also it contains a value which is the address of `a` so `pointer` needs to be stored somewhere since it contains a value

Comment: It could be in a register or nowhere at all, because its value can be statically calculated during compilation.

Comment: @KenZa: It's very common in C++ for things to have an address **if and when** they need one. That's pretty automatic. Some things don't get addresses automatically, though, such as temporaries like `2+2`. You'd need to store that result somewhere yourself if you want an address.

Comment: @KenZa Yes, `pointer` is a variable, but the compiler will store its value somewhere only if it needs to, and if it does noeed to, objects with automatic storage are stored in registers as much as possible since it's very much faster than accessing memory.

Comment: @molbdnilo so  you're saying that if the compiler doesn't need to "output" pointer but only have access to it , then it would be stored in a register instead of a memory ?

Answer (score 0):

In the first code `poiner` stores the address of variable `a`, and by command.

```
std::cout<<pointer<<std::endl;
```

You print the address of `a`. That's it.
In the second code `pointer` also stores the address of variable `a`, but `&pointer` is the address of variable `pointer`. Try the following

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    int a = 5;
    void* pointer = &a;
    void** pointer_to_pointer = &pointer;
    std::cout << a << std::endl << &a << std::endl << pointer << std::endl;
    std::cout << &pointer << std::endl << pointer_to_pointer;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

The output for me is

```
5
0x7aba1bd92e94
0x7aba1bd92e94
0x7aba1bd92e98
0x7aba1bd92e98
```

Comment: yeah i know about is , this is not my problem, my problem is why would the address of `a` change between the two programs since all i did is change the output which should not affect the memory

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple.
`int a` and `void* pointer` are two distinct variables or I better say **memory locations** on the stack. `a` holds a value like 5 in its location. `pointer` holds the address to `a`'s memory location. `pointer` itself is stored in a different location and when you write `std::cout << &pointer << std::endl;` it will print the address of the `pointer` variable, not the contents of it which is `a`'s address.

As a simplified example:

Consider **0x4** as the address of `pointer` itself and the value inside it is **0xC**. This value points to `a`'s location. In order to read the value of `a`(which is 5), you first have to go to **0x4** to read its content. Its content is **0xC** and now you have successfully found out that `a`'s location is **0xC**. Then you have to go to **0xC** and at that address, you will find the value 5.

You look at -> **0x4**( content == **0xC** ) -> **0xC**( content == **5** ) -> done!